# How to override "not default" attribute by vagrant with chef-solo?

Tags: chef-infra, vagrant

## Question

I'm using vagrant with chef-solo provision.

1. How to override "**not** default" attribute?
2. If I will create chef-recipe, When should I use "**not** default" attribute?

## Description

I saw `openldap['rootpw']` in [attribute of openldap](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/openldap/blob/a49dc8cf89d7f7345e011bdc65cd3858a3a8978e/attributes/default.rb#L27)

I would like to override `openldap['rootpw']` of attribute.

I tried to override configuration, following like

```
# Vagrantfile
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|

    #....

    chef.json = {
      'rootpw' => 'xxxx....',
      'openldap' => {
        'rootpw' => 'xxxx....'
      }
    }
  end
end
```

But, attribute was not overridden.

I think, it could override if attribute was `default['openldap']['rootpw']`.

How to override "**not** default" attribute?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use override attributes. [You can set them in different places](http://wiki.opscode.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=8257848) (recipe, role, environment), perhaps you can find the suitable for you.

Comment: What would this look like as a `chef.json` value?

Comment: I don't think it's possible through chef.json. Most likely it's imported as `default` attributes, thus they are not able to overwrite any `normal` or `override` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot override a "not default" attribute as easily as a default because it evaluates lower down the chain. Basically, the order is a continuum of default, force_default, normal,override, force_override, automatic.  If you want something to be overridden just go further down the list.  It's best practice to use defaults and override them.

http://docs.opscode.com/essentials_cookbook_attribute_files.html#attribute-precedence